# Dictionary Key look up with variable length inputs

Tags: c#, hash-map

I am decoding GS1 barcodes and need to match up application identifiers with relevant data about them.

> ```
> 00    SSCC (Serial Shipping Container Code)   N2+N18  FALSE   SSCC 
> 01    Global Trade Item Number (GTIN)         N2+N14  FALSE   GTIN 
> 02    GTIN of Contained Trade Items           N2+N14  FALSE   CONTENT 
> 10    Batch or Lot Number                     N2+X.20 TRUE    BATCH/LOT 
> 11    Production Date (YYMMDD)                N2+N6   FALSE   PROD DATE 
> 12    Due Date (YYMMDD)                       N2+N6   FALSE   DUE DATE 
> 13    Packaging Date (YYMMDD)                 N2+N6   FALSE   PACK DATE 
> 15    Best Before Date (YYMMDD)               N2+N6   FALSE   BEST BEFORE or BEST BY 
> 16    Sell By Date (YYMMDD)                   N2+N6   FALSE   SELL BY 
> 17    Expiration Date (YYMMDD)                N2+N6   FALSE   USE BY OR EXPIRY 
> 20    Variant Number                          N2+N2   FALSE   VARIANT 
> 21    Serial Number                           N2+X.20 TRUE    SERIAL 
> 240   Additional Item Identification          N3+X.30 TRUE    ADDITIONAL ID 
> 241   Customer Part Number                    N3+X.30 TRUE    CUST. PART NO. 
> 242   Made-to-Order Variation Number          N3+N.6  TRUE    MTO VARIANT 
> 243   Packaging Component Number              N3+X.20 TRUE    PCN 
> 250   Secondary Serial Number                 N3+X.30 TRUE    SECONDARY SERIAL 
> 251   Reference to Source Entity              N3+X.30 TRUE    REF. TO SOURCE 
> 253   Global Document Type Identifier (GDTI)  N3+N13+XTRUE    GDTI 
> 254   GLN Extension Component                 N3+X.20 TRUE    GLN EXTENSION COMPONENT 
> 255   Global Coupon Number (GCN)              N3+N13+NTRUE    GCN 
> 30    Count of Items (Variable Measu ...      N2+N..8 TRUE    VAR. COUNT 
> 3100  Net weight  kilograms (Var... )     N4+N6   FALSE   NET WEIGHT (kg) 
> ...
> ```

[Full list here.](http://www.databar-barcode.info/application-identifiers/)

This is how I identify them:

```cs
public Dictionary<int, Tuple<string, string, bool, string>> gs1AiDict { get; private set; } 

var aiDataOut = new Tuple<string, string, bool, string>("","",false,"");

//Get first 4 digits (max identifier length)
//the string input pi might look like this: ~10000123
int applicationIdentifier = Convert.ToInt16(pi.Substring(1,4));
//Try to find an identifier with 2 digits.
if (gs1AiDict.TryGetValue(applicationIdentifier / 100, out aiDataOut))
{
    //assign found data to tuple
    id = aiDataOut.Item1;
    format = aiDataOut.Item2;
    func = aiDataOut.Item3;
    abrv = aiDataOut.Item4;
}
//look up the first 3 digits
else
{
    if (gs1AiDict.TryGetValue(applicationIdentifier / 10, out aiDataOut))
    {
        id = aiDataOut.Item1;
        format = aiDataOut.Item2;
        func = aiDataOut.Item3;
        abrv = aiDataOut.Item4;
    }
    //look up first 4 digits
    else
    {
        if (gs1AiDict.TryGetValue(applicationIdentifier, out aiDataOut))
        {
            id = aiDataOut.Item1;
            format = aiDataOut.Item2;
            func = aiDataOut.Item3;
            abrv = aiDataOut.Item4;
        }
        //no identifiers are 5 digits
        else
        {
         console.log("No Application Identifier found!");
        }
    }
}
```

My tests have worked wonderfully, but my issue is the readability and efficiency of this solution. Are 3 dictionary key look ups for about 140 keys too much?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Code duplication is a sin

You could use shorter and more readable code using a simple for loop:

```
int applicationIdentifier = Convert.ToInt16(pi.Substring(1,4));
for (int i = 100; i >= 1; i /= 10)
{
    int maybeId = applicationIdentifier / i;
    if (gs1AiDict.TryGetValue(maybeId, out aiDataOut))
    {
        id = aiDataOut.Item1;
        format = aiDataOut.Item2;
        func = aiDataOut.Item3;
        abrv = aiDataOut.Item4;
        return;
    }
}   
Console.WriteLine("No Application Identifier found!");
```

You should also consider making your data object something along the lines of a `Dicitionary<int, ApplicationInfo>`, that 4-member tuple doesn't help readibility. Then you could also return an `ApplicationInfo` object instead of copying the fields to local variables.

Comment: Indeed that function is much cleaner.  Regarding the use of "Application Info" to hold the data: could you point me to a use of that? When I was researching how to get multiple parameters per key, all I found were Tuples.

Comment: @Phyre `ApplicationInfo` is a name I made up, it's not a existing type. I was suggesting that you should create a class that holds a single entry of application information.